# Why is google chrome rendering certain webfonts like this?

Tags: google-chrome

I'm working on a website currently that uses google's web font "Open Sans", but everywhere the font is rendered wrong.  I looked at Dropbox.com and it also has the same problem (they use Open Sans as well). It looks like this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/fh1eyb2oiysop5k/crap.png

When I view the site in firefox, it looks normal.  When I copy the text and paste in a text file, the actual text that supposed to be there IS there.

I've been following the issue at http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=108645

Answer (score 2):

It's a bug! Chrome has anti-aliasing issues with many of Google's own web fonts.

You'll gain a better visual in Chrome using [embedded fonts](http://www.onextrapixel.com/2011/05/03/understanding-and-using-embedded-fonts-what-why-and-how/).